Investigate whether $f_n (x)=\dfrac{nx}{1+n^3x^3}$ on $[0,\infty),n\in \mathbb N$ converges uniformly or not.
Investigate whether $f_n (x)=\dfrac{nx}{1+n^3x^3}$ on $[0,\infty),n\in \mathbb N$ converges uniformly or not.
Obviously, $f_n(x)$ pointwise converges to $0$. Since $f_n(0)=0$ when $x=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_ {n\to \infty} f_n(x)=\dfrac{nx}{1+n^3x^3}=0$ for $x \in (0,\infty)$. Therefore $f_n(x)$ can converge uniformly to $0$. To show that it indeed converges to $0$, we need to check the following.
$M_n=\displaystyle\sup_{x\in [0,\infty)} |f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$. It turns out that $M_n=\displaystyle\sup_{x\in [0,\infty)} |\dfrac{nx}{1+n^3x^3}-0|=\sup|\dfrac{nx}{1+n^3x^3}|$.
I want to play with inequalities so as to do I checked first derivative of $\dfrac{nx}{1+n^3x^3}$ which gives when function takes its maximum but I couldn't obtain something useful. After that I tried the following simply however I couldn't get rid of the term $x$.
$M_n=\displaystyle\sup_{x\in [0,\infty)} |\dfrac{nx}{1+n^3x^3}-0|=\sup|\dfrac{nx}{1+n^3x^3}|\le\sup|\dfrac{nx}{n^3x^3}|=\sup|\dfrac{1}{n^2x^2}|$
Thanks in advance.

Hint: What is $f_n(1/n)$ ?

Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3331749/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3003598/42969

$M_n=\sup_{y\ge0}\frac y{1+y^3}>0$ doesn't depend on $n$ hence cannot tend to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

could you eleborate more?

What is not clear to you? 1) the equality? 2), the middle of the sentence (before "hence")? 3) the end (after "hence")? 4) Why this completely answers your question? 5) Something else?
